# SQL query. I would like to create a search that returns either the name of a contact, or the name of a company(and it's contact)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have three tables (because this involves a many to many relationship):

```
tblContact     tblContCompJunction   tblCompany
ContactID      ContactID             CompanyID          
ContactName    CompanyID             CompanyName
```

Currently my Query is built as such:

```
Select ContactID, CompanyID, ContactName, CompanyName,(ContactName & CompanyName) As SearchConcat
FROM (tblContact LEFT JOIN tblContCompJunction ON tblContact.ContactID = tblContCompJunction.ContactID) 
LEFT JOIN tblCompany ON tblContCompJunction.CompanyID = tblCompany.CompanyID;
```

The problem I have is that I can't get the Contact listed alone when it has a relatable company. I need the search to determine between selecting a company and a contact, and that is where this fails.

Comment: So what is the logic here?  If company <> null, show company and contact, otherwise show contact only?

Comment: Jo Smo is the contact at company ABC Farms, and is the contact at ABC Irrigation. I would like the query to return Jo 3 times. Once for ea company and once by himself. Currently it returns Jo only 2 times (once for ea associated company).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want each `ContactName` *"Once for each company and once by himself."*

This query will give you each `ContactName` as himself.

```sql
SELECT
    tblContact.ContactName,
    'himself' AS CompanyName
FROM tblContact
```

And this query will give you a row for each `ContactName`/`CompanyName` pair.

```sql
SELECT
    tblContact.ContactName,
    tblCompany.CompanyName
FROM
    (tblContact
    INNER JOIN tblContCompJunction
    ON tblContact.ContactID = tblContCompJunction.ContactID)
    INNER JOIN tblCompany
    ON tblContCompJunction.CompanyID = tblCompany.CompanyID
```

Use Access' query designer to set up those joins in case I made an error in that untested SQL.

Once you have both queries working correctly, you can use a `UNION` query to combine them.

```sql
SELECT
    tblContact.ContactName,
    'himself' AS CompanyName
FROM tblContact
UNION ALL
SELECT
    tblContact.ContactName,
    tblCompany.CompanyName
FROM
    (tblContact
    INNER JOIN tblContCompJunction
    ON tblContact.ContactID = tblContCompJunction.ContactID)
    INNER JOIN tblCompany
    ON tblContCompJunction.CompanyID = tblCompany.CompanyID
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I knew a Union somehow, but could not get my brain to wrap around it right. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Select ContactID, CompanyID, ContactName, CompanyName,IsNull(CompanyName, ContactName) As SearchConcat
FROM (tblContact LEFT JOIN tblContCompJunction ON tblContact.ContactID = tblContCompJunction.ContactID)
LEFT JOIN tblCompany ON tblContCompJunction.CompanyID = tblCompany.CompanyID;
```